# FileReader readAsDataURL creating large base64 images

Tags: javascript, base64, filereader

I have a requirement to convert an input image (blob) to base64 image. Im aware the size will increase by approx 1.37.

However i have noticed when using the `firereader.readAsDataUrl` the size of the image is extremely large when compared to the built in base64 command line tool you have on macOS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download this free sample image https://wall.alphacoders.com/big.php?i=685897 make sure to click the Download button (Downlaod Original 8000x600). Do not use right click save as because the image will be compressed
2. Use the jsfiddle to pick the above downloaded image and check the console log for the size of the base 64. https://jsfiddle.net/b7nkw8j9/ you can see the size is **11.2mb**.
3. Now if your on mac use the base64 command line tool to convert the above downloaded image to base64 and check the file size there. You will see the base64 size here is. **5.9mb**. `base64 -w 0 downloaded_image.jpg > downloaded_image.base64`

This is the function i am using in my code to convert an input file image to base64.

```
async convertToBase64(file) {

  if (file === undefined) {
    throw new Error("File could not be found");
  }

  const fileReader = new FileReader();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
      reject("Input: File could not be read:" + error);
    };

    fileReader.onloadend = () => {
      resolve(fileReader.result);
    };
  });

}
```

Why does the `filereader.readAsDataURL` make the image base64 output extremely large.

How can i make this more efficient?

[image]

Comment: @Kaiido sorry i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean I don't have 11.2MB but a string of length 5,882,455 containing only ASCII safe characters (e.g a 5.9MB utf-8 text file)

Comment: how? i can see in the console window 11.2mb what have you changed?

Comment: How do you see 11.2mb? [The fiddle you linked to](https://jsfiddle.net/b7nkw8j9/) only outputs the string.

Comment: @Kaiido please see the screenshot i sent ive displayed in my question it shows 11.2mb in console window.

Comment: Ah you mean this non sense tooltip from Chrome's broken console? Dunno what they're talking about. [Look at this instead](https://jsfiddle.net/h7n49d6x/) to know what you're doing.

Comment: Is this tooltip broken?!?! are you sure?

Comment: i have been testing against this chrome console window so this number has been very misleading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have 5,882,455 bytes for the FileReader vs 5,882,433 bytes for `base64` output,  if you add the 22 bytes from `data:image/png;base64,`, we're not too far.

However to the question *How can i make this more efficient?*, just don't use a data URL here. Whatever you've been told you need it too, it was a lie (I'm 99% percent sure).

Instead you should always prefer to work with the Blob directly.

To display it, use a blob URL:

```js
inp.onchange = e => {
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(inp.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
<img id="img" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview..." accept="image/*">
```

To send it to your server, [send the Blob directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), either through a FormData or, directly from xhr.send() or as the body of a fetch request.

The only case  can think of where you would need a data URL version of a binary file on the front end is to generate a standalone document which would need to embed that binary file. For all other use cases I met in my career, Blob where far better suited.

---

For the message that gets printed in the Chrome's tooltip, that's the size of the [USVString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString) that the browser has to hold in memory. It's twice the size of the file you have on disk, because USVStrings are encoded in UTF-16, even though this string holds only ASCII characters.
However, to be sent to your server, or to be saved as a text file, it will generally be reencoded in an 8 bit encoding, and retrieve it's normal size.

So don't take this tooltip as a mean to tell you how big your data is, it's only the size it does take in the browser's allocated memory, but outside, it won't be the same at all.

If you wanna check the size of binary data generated here is a better fiddle, which will convert USVStrings to UTF-8 and keep binary as binary (e.g if you pass an ArrayBuffer to it):

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log(new Blob([reader.result]).size);
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL -->

<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

Comment: " if you add the 22 bytes from data:image/png;base64,, we're not too far." can you explain what you mean by this, it looks like you altered something to make it closer to the size and i want to know what . you changed in the steps i provided

Comment: Absolultely not, what I mean here is that `5,882,433` from `base64` + 22 from the data URL header = `5,882,455` from the FileReader, which is correct since the FileReader outputs a data URL, while `base64` only outputs the base 64 encoded version of the binary data.

Comment: Unfortunately we are forced to use base64 right now and cannot use a blob. My main issue is why im seeing 11.2mb

Comment: (That's a lie) but I won't force you ;-) And for the message I added a foot note with a better test for the bytes size of generated binary data in a browser.

Comment: the number is correct, although decieving. You're not dealing with a sequence of bytes, you're dealing with a String in JS. JS Strings store 16bit/character. So `5882455 characters * 2 byte/character / 1024 / 1024` ~ 11.2MB in of memory allocated. If you check the `length` of the string you'll see the "correct" number.

Comment: @Thomas you are absolutely correct, though the *length* of the string would be correct here only because we are dealing with base64 data, if we had a string like `"안영"`, then `.length` would output *2*, while it would take 6bytes encoded in UTF-8.