# Canvas toDataUrl image result (png base64) size is larger than expected! Twice as large

Tags: canvas, base64, fabricjs

I've got FabricJS running, a user can add text/images on a product, manipulate them, then purchase the product. My plan is as the user finishes the design, I would export the canvas as png base64, and send it to the server in JSON (it'll be somewhat large, but i can take that hit, i have to, to preserve printing quality).

The canvas size i'm working with is - width: 1600 & height: 2400

I am expecting base64 images to be 137% of the original size of their PNG counterparts, but what I am getting is about 280% the original size.

The test I did was:

- add anything to the canvas
- export and console.log the base64 image
- used multiple tools online to decode base64 to png, and then encode back to base64, and these are my results:

Test 1 - Adding a full size image & exporting it:

1. Initial base64 image size on canvas export: 12.6mb
2. After converting to PNG: 4851 kb
3. After encoding the same PNG back to base64: 6576 kb (this is the size i am expecting on initial export)
4. After decoding the resulting halfsize base64 back to PNG again: 4851 kb (the exact same result as the large base64)

Test 2 - Done with a simple text element, pretty much the same result ratios.

Main online tools I've used for encoding/decoding are:

- https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-base64-to-png
- https://www.base64encode.org/

The method I am using to export the canvas (its built in vueJS, irrelevant info but just for context):

```
    exportCanvas() {
      const exportedArt = this.canvas.toDataURL({
        format: "png"
      });
      this.exportedArt = exportedArt;
      const exportedArtThumbnail = this.canvas.toDataURL({
        format: "png",
        multiplier: 0.2
      });
      console.log("Exported Art:", exportedArt);
      console.log("Exported Thumbnail:", exportedArtThumbnail);
    }
```

I tried checking the pixelRatio thing, my device has a pixel ratio of 1, so thats not the issue. I also know the whole "retinaScaling" thing isn't an issue here.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized this whole confusion on my original base64 export was due to the chrome console reading the base64 size incorrectly.

I manually checked my original base64 export size outside the console and everything checks out correctly. I am getting the expected 6576 kb. So the console.log size estimation of strings was just throwing me off.

There is no issue here, just incorrect reading of string size from the chrome console.

Comment: That's because the string is encoded in utf16 in the browser's memory, so they just tell you that size, even though indeed it makes no sense outside of the browser where a base64 string can safely be encoded in ascii or utf8 and hence take up half the utf16 size. An other question which has been triggered by this same confusing console message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890549/filereader-readasdataurl-creating-large-base64-images/56890823#56890823